# What are the differences of the different type code used in Python arrays?

Tags: python

In the python standard library for arrays, the table of type code is specified into C type and Python type. While the C type seems to have a differentiation for each type code, Python type has a repetitive data type for multiple type code. What is the difference of them in Python if there are any?

[Table in python library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

I do not understand C language so all the other explanations out there I am struggling to understand. Please try to answer in a way that I may understand without C knowledge.

Comment: I think it just tells you that python types encompass multiple C types, i.e. less granularity in Python than in C. Not sure what else you are asking...

Comment: C is statically typed. That means you have to declare variables with an specific type. e.g: array of chars ```char x[128]```. Lists in python can hold items from any kind (a single list may have integers and strings for example). On the other hand, ```array``` emulates a C array (all items are of the same kind).